# terraform plan throws unwanted "update in place" even though resource has not changed at all

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the following CLoudSQL resource in a module:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "myCloudSql" {

  name             = "my-sql-name-${var.environment}"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "POSTGRES_##"

  depends_on = [
   ...
  ]



  settings {
    tier              = "db-f1-micro"
    availability_type = "ZONAL"
    disk_size         = var.diskSize
    disk_type         = var.diskType

    backup_configuration {
      enabled = true
    }

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = true
      private_network = var.myVpcId

      ...
      
    }
  }
}
```

If I ran `terraform plan` I get:

```
  # module.myCloudSql.google_sql_database_instance.myCloudSql will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_sql_database_instance" "myCloudSql" {
        id                             = "my-sql-name-env"
        name                           = "my-sql-name-env"
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

Why is this happening and how to avoid it from attempting to update in place if no change was done neither any change needed for my CloudSql Resource?

Comment: @MattSchuchard this is a GCP question, not an AWS question. It's apparently a bug in the GCP provider.

Comment: Getting something similar with azure function apps :(